# Detect the important part of a receipt (CNN)

Tags: cnn, object-detection, image-preprocessing

In general I want to detect prices and products from a receipt. My approach was to detect the important part of the receipt (products with their prices) to then afterwards pass to firebase ml kit to detect text (OCR).

I build my model already but I'm stuck on the preprocessing part here.

I figured stretching the images to a fixed size and grayscaling it or even make it only black and white. What I don't get since I'm resizing each picture, how do I have to change the coordinates (labels as seen from AI perspective) from the polygon since I'm resizing the picture? Furthermore how should I rotate the bill to be perfectly level?

Any suggestions or help really appreciated!